# Cucumber with TestNG

Tags: cucumber, bdd, testng

We have a very extensive framework in TestNG with Selenium WebDriver and I want to be able to continue using it, but use Cucumber BDD with it.I am aware that Cucumber works with JUnit, but not sure if it works with TestNG.

Can anyone let me know if this is going to be available anytime soon ? If not, are there any workarounds so that I can use Cucumber with TestNG?

Also, are there any other BDDs that are available in the market which can be used with TestNG ?

Answer (score 8):

Dependency in maven's pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Test running the features:

```
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

public class CucumberTets extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

Comment: I posted the solution to simplify life of future readers of this question.

Comment: It's of utmost importance to remove other testNg dependecies in your pom then. Or else only classic tests will be interpretted. (I struggled with it today so I thought it was worth sharing)