# TestNG with Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, testng

I am running cucumber with testNG. CucumberRunner class extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests and CucumberRunner class is specified in testNG.xml file.

If I run a simple TestNG class with testNG.xml then output for testNG results gets displayed in console i.e Total tests run, Failures, Skips as shown below:-

Test.java

```
package com.cucumber.test;
import org.testng.Assert;
public class Test {
@org.testng.annotations.Test
public void test() {
    Assert.assertEquals(true, true);
}
}
```

testNG.xml:-

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="TestNG" verbose="1">
<test name="TestCuke">
<classes>
<class name="com.cucumber.test.Test">
</class>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

[image]

But when I run testNG.xml with CucumberRunner then the output for testNG results are not getting displayed in console.

testNG.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="TestNG" verbose="1">
<test name="TestCuke">
<classes>
<class name="com.cucumber.test.CucumberRunner">
</class>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

CucumberRunner.java

```
package com.cucumber.test;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
simport cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(tags= "@smokeTest",features="src\\newTestFile.feature")
public class CucumberRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{
}
```

[image]

How to display testNG results output in console with cucumber?

Comment: What logging configuration do you have? slf or logback?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cucumber with TestNG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595047/cucumber-with-testng)

Answer (score 2):

To integrate JUnit cucumber tests with TestNG we need to Follow 3 Steps

**STEP 1 :**
In TestNG xml add path and name of CucumberRunner / TestRunner file in class tag.

This allows TestNG to locate cucumber's TestRunner File

**STEP 2:**
In CucumberRunner / TestRunner file extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests

This allows Cucumber Tests to be run on TestNG instead of JUnit

**STEP 3**
In Maven add cucumber-testNG dependency

This provides supporting Jars for cucumber and TestNG integration to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a parameter in test.java and testng.xml like that:

```
package com.cucumber.test;
import org.testng.Assert;
public class Test {
@org.testng.annotations.Test("myTest")
public void test() {
    Assert.assertEquals(true, true);
}
}

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="TestNG" verbose="1">
<test name="TestCuke">
<parameter name="myName"  value="true"/>
<classes>
<class name="com.cucumber.test.Test">
</class>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the detailed report in the console, by adding **"*pretty*"** as on of the **format** options under ***@CucumberOptions***.

Eg.,

```
@CucumberOptions(
        format={"pretty","json:path/to/json_repot.json"},
        features = "Path_to_features_file",
        glue="com.sri.stepDefinition",
        tags={"@smoke,@regression")
        )

public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{}
```